# How to send a string literal along with json object in java?

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, json, servlets

I am using 2 different `mysql queries` in `if and else`. In both `if and else` i am sending a `json object` to the client which I serialized from `java object` by using `GSON library` and then further manipulating it on the client side using jquery. In the client side `jquery ajax` method I have to identify that from which portion of the server side code this json object is coming. For example is it from if part or from else part . Lets say I sent a String_literal in `out.println(json+"string_literal")` then further I don't know how to check for it on client side jquery ajax method .Can u Tell me how can I extract this `string`. Every time I try to extract this string or do something else , I messed up with json object.  I want to do something like this....

```
 success:function(data){
            if(JSON HAS STRING ALONG WITH IT)
           {
             // do this
           }
           else
          {  
                // this
            productContainer.innerHTML ="";
            var $productContainer = $('#productContainer');
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
            $productContainer.append("<div id='productBox' class='grid_3'>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><img src='"+value["image"]+"'/></a><br/>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><span class='black'>"+value['name']+"</span></a><br/>\n\
             <span class='black'>By "+value['company']+"</span><br/><span class='red'>RS."+value['price']+"</span></div>");                                                                                                                                
       }                       
        }) ;
      }
```

**EDIT SERVER-SIDE CODE**

```
  ArrayList<product> p = new ArrayList();
  ps = con.prepareStatement("some query");
  ps.setInt(1,p_id.get(i));
  rs=ps.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next())
   {
     product pr =new product();
     pr.id = rs.getInt("product_id");
     pr.name = rs.getString("product_name");
     pr.company =rs.getString("company_name");
     pr.image = rs.getString("image_name");
     pr.price = rs.getDouble("price");
     p.add(pr);        
   }       

  }

    String json = new Gson().toJson(p);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    out.println(json);
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not just add the variable to your JSON object?

Comment: You can put that variable in the JSON and check for it with your `data` parameter.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i have added the server side code can u please tell me how to do it now.

Comment: What's `p`? An array? `ArrayList<Product>`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to parse a concatenated variable outside the JSON braces, I suggest you to add that variable inside the JSON.

If you choose to add the variable using GSON, you should add this to your java class, then parse it.

Example:

Add your variable to java class.

```
public class Envelope{
    private Array<Product> products;
    private Boolean newVariable;
    ... 
    // getter's and setter's
}
```

Parse your object using GSON:

```
Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
envelope.setNewVariable(true);
envelope.setProducts(products);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(envelope);
```

Then print your string on your JSP

```
out.print(jsonString)
```

Finally, on JQuery side, if ajax request is successful, then you should be able to see your variable at

```
success:function(data){
        if( data.newVariable == true) // suppose new variable is boolean
       {
         // do this
         var products[] = data.products;
       } else {
           // do other thing
       }
}
```

Comment: So u mean i have to add a new variable into the product class?

Comment: if you need the new variable for each product, then yes. If you only need one variable for your array, you could create a class that envelopes your list as attribute, add your variable in the envelope class, and then parse the envelope using GSON.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach is to just add this variable to your JSON response. You could create an additional class to wrap your product list and this additional variable, or just use a map as follows:

```
// ... create your product ArrayList as before

Map<String, ?> result = new HashMap<>();
result.put("variable", "some_value");
result.put("products", p);

String json = new Gson().toJson(result);
response.setContentType("application/json");
out.println(json);
```

And then on the client side:

```
success: function(data) {
   if (data.variable === 'some value') {
       // do your stuff
   } else {
       // ...

       $.each(data.products, function(key, value) { /* ... */ }
   }
}
```